# How to print out the contents of a nested vector in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

The following is the snippet in doubt:

```
typedef std::vector<unsigned char> QInput; // defined in an external library

std::vector<QInput> extvec; // defined in a separate function
```

**Question 1:** Is `extvec` a nested vector?

**Question 2:** How do I print out the contents of `extvec`?

I've tried printing out the contents of `extvec` using the conventional method described in many answers at StackOverflow, but I'm getting a lot of errors. So I decided that this might be a nested vector. But the form looks different from other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130243/pretty-printing-nested-vectors).

Comment: "I'm getting a lot of errors" - we could probably help with those if we knew what they were. There are several ways to print a vector of vectors, [these being just a few](http://ideone.com/zWsYae).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is `extvec` a nested vector?

There's no such thing as a "nested vector". It's a vector of vectors.

> How do I print out the contents of `extvec`?

By iterating through the vectors in it.

Answer (score 6):

**Is extvec a nested vector?**
Yes you can imagine that way but not as official term.

**How do I print out the contents of extvec?**

In c++98:

```
for (std::vector<QInput>::iterator it = extvec.begin(); it != extvec.end(); ++it)
    {
        for (vector<unsigned char>::iterator it1 = (*it).begin(); it1 != (*it).end(); ++it1)
        {
            cout << *it1 << endl;
        }
    }
```

In c++11 std:

```
for (const auto& v : extvec)
{
    for (auto i : v)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using const auto& instead of just auto to avoid copies if you only want to print something. :)